# Bootstrap modal works on inner pages but not works on home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to load a popup on home page using bootstrap modal, it works perfectly on inner page but getting error on home home page

```
TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
```

i loaded these two on every pages

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://zobezorgd.nl/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://zobezorgd.nl/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and every pages seems load same javascript libraries, so i'm not sure why i'm getting this messages only on home page

home page url http://zobezorgd.nl/

inner page url http://zobezorgd.nl/restaurantDetails.php?resid=47&resname=new-york-pizza

username: zozo

password: zozo

can anyone help me to fix this please, i tired lots of hours. Thank You

Comment: For one, you're loading jQuery multiple times. Once in the head `http://zobezorgd.nl/js/jquery-1.10.2.js` and once at the end of the page `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: agree with @vanburen if you remove the 2nd jQuery lib, modal will show

Comment: You have a lot of scripts loaded, maybe exists an incompatibility with them. Try to disable all except jquery and bootstrap and step by step enable each one. Edit: Probably the problem will be fixed with the message of @vanburen

Comment: @vanburen thanks its working after remove jquery which loaded from google, if you can write that as a answer i can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're loading jQuery twice on your page**.

Once in the head:

`http://zobezorgd.nl/js/jquery-1.10.2.js`

and again at the end of the page:

`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`.

Remove one.